# How to make a popup appear on the exact location of App's TASKBAR Button

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-7

I am currently popping up a popup near the SysTray icons when Application.OnActivate occurs.
however I need to popup it now where the App button was clicked on TaskBar (next to start menu).
How to find out the exact location of my app's taskbar icon that was just clicked?

I know I could simply allow the App Form appear and ask user to click a button that makes a popup to appear, but I need more simpler/faster to use GUI for my App.

```
if (mode = 2) or ( (x =0) and (y=0) ) then begin
     ABData.cbSize := SizeOf(TAppBarData);
     //ABData.hWnd := FindWindow('Shell_TrayWnd', nil);
     SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETTASKBARPOS, ABData);
     with ABData.Rc do begin
        if (Top > 0) then Edge := ABE_BOTTOM
        else if (Bottom < Screen.Height) then Edge := ABE_TOP
        else if Right < Screen.Width then Edge := ABE_LEFT
        else Edge := ABE_RIGHT;
     end;
     X := 1; Y := 1;
     if Edge = ABE_BOTTOM then begin
        X := ABData.Rc.Right-20;
        Y := ABData.Rc.Top;
     end else if Edge = ABE_TOP then begin
        X := ABData.Rc.Right;
        Y := ABData.Rc.Top;
     end else if Edge = ABE_LEFT then begin
        X := ABData.Rc.Left;
        Y := ABData.Rc.Bottom;
     end else if Edge = ABE_RIGHT then begin
        X := ABData.Rc.Right;
        Y := ABData.Rc.Bottom;
     end;

  end;
```

Comment: What if the taskbar is not shown or auto hides? What if it consists of more than one line/column?

Comment: Autohide is OK;  I just need the coordinates where mouse click did occur  so that user can see the popup where they clicked

Comment: @Tom then why not simply install a mouse hook and capture the screen coordinates at the time the click is made and before it is processed?

Comment: Excellent idea!

Comment: Keep in mind that those buttons can be pressed by keyboard alone, too, while the mouse cursor is elsewhere. Activating your application's window can be done entirely without using a mouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the easiest solution was to check mouse position and pop where  mouse was:

```
 pt := Mouse.CursorPos;
 x := pt.x;
 y:= pt.y;
```

PS: there seems to be also another solution in C# and C++:

[How to find TaskBar button screen Rect of a window?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/115440/how-to-find-taskbar-button-screen-rect-of-a-window.html)

Answer (score 1):

If by "taskbar icon" you mean a system tray icon that you own, then you can use [`Shell_NotifyIconGetRect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shell_notifyicongetrect).  But, if you mean a Taskbar button instead, then there is no (official) way to determine its location on the Taskbar.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the taskbar _button_ is meant, and since nowadays (e.g. Windows 10) by default they only show up as icons without text anymore (and nothing is painted flat so buttons are hard to distinguish from links) it has become a "taskbar icon".

Comment: Actually I meant the big buttons that each software has one,  in Windows11 these are on the bottom next to start button.  Yes  there is no official way, that's why I ask here;)

Comment: @Tom yes, you, AmigoJack and I are referring to the same thing. There is no API to query information about a given window's Taskbar button.

Comment: Just reading this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/115440/how-to-find-taskbar-button-screen-rect-of-a-window.html

Comment: @Tom that approach relies on private implementation details that can and do change between Windows versions.